# How to convert jQuery append in javascript vanilla?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the following Javascript method:

```
document.createElement('div');
```

But here is my jQuery code and HTML to generate :

```
var add_html = "<div class='card'><a href='#'><div'><img class='img-fluid' src='"+image+"' alt='picture'><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'>"+name+"</h5></div></div></a></div>";
$("#my_div").append(add_html);
```

How can I do it using the vanilla javascript ?

The goal is to use in `bricklayer.append(document.createElement('div'));`

Comment: ``.innerHTML`` can be used in vanilla javascript

Comment: `document.getElementById("my_div").append(add_html)`

Comment: I think your looking for document.appendChild

Comment: I got the following error Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: @EthanVu `appendChild` takes a node as an argument, not an HTML string.

Comment: @Yousaf Which `.createElement("div")` returns

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: @Andreas right but i am assuming OP wants to append `add_html` which is a string. Not to mention that `append` will work with a node as well as a string.

Comment: The [jQuery.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js) uses `appendChild()` for `$append`, but I prefer `append()`

Comment: @Yousaf _"I'm trying to use the following Javascript method: `document.createElement('div');"_

Comment: Two methods you need to create the required HTML hierarchy are [append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) and [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Once you have the required HTML hierarchy, just do: `document.getElementById("my_div").append(add_html) ` where `add_html` is the outermost `div` element with the class of `card`.

Comment: `append` is far away from being vanilla js. My IPhone 4 needs a Polyfill for it, so i would not classify it as vanilla.js

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) like the following way:

```js
var image = '/../john.jpg'
var name = 'John';
var add_html = "<div class='card'><a href='#'><div'><img class='img-fluid' src='"+image+"' alt='picture'><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'>"+name+"</h5></div></div></a></div>";

document.getElementById('my_div').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', add_html);
```

```html
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Comment: Still getting `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML()` worked better for me than `append()`  but i had to use `'beforeend'` instead of `'afterend'` to get the result i want in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can create the element, append it, and then alter the outer HTML.

Use a template literal for easy code maintainability.

```js
const
  div   = document.createElement('div'),
  name  = 'Hello World',
  image = 'http://placekitten.com/g/280/120';

document.querySelector('#my-div').append(div);

div.outerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <div'>
        <img class="img-fluid" src="${image}" alt="picture">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
`;
```

```css
#my-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.card-body > .card-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: I need to use in `bricklayer.append(document.createElement('div'));`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var image = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';
    var name = 'Hello World';
    var div = document.getElementById('my_div').appendChild( document.createElement('div') );
    div.classList.add('card');
    
    var a = div.appendChild( document.createElement('a') );
    a.href = '#';
    
    var anotherDiv = a.appendChild( document.createElement('div') );
    var img = anotherDiv.appendChild( document.createElement('img') );
    img.classList.add('img-fluid');
    img.src = image;
    img.alt = 'picture';
    
    var anotherNotherDiv = anotherDiv.appendChild( document.createElement('div') );
    anotherNotherDiv.classList.add('card-body');
    var h5 = anotherNotherDiv.appendChild( document.createElement('h5') );
    h5.classList.add('card-title');
    h5.innerText = name;
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is some syntax error as `createEelement` and here is the output : `<div class="card"></div>`

Comment: beacause I misspelled `Element` could happens